# Put some categories as column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table looking like this:

| Month | Region | Category | Size | Brand | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Canada | T-shirts | S | Nike | 100 |
| January | Canada | T-shirts | S | Reebok | 150 |
| January | Canada | T-shirts | S | Puma | 200 |
| January | Canada | Jacket | S | Nike | 200 |
| January | Canada | Jacket | S | Reebok | 300 |
| January | USA | Jacket | L | Puma | 400 |
| January | USA | Jacket | L | Reebok | 500 |

1. I want to make table looking like this (no aggregation functions needed):

| Month | Region | Category | Size | Nike | Reebok | Puma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Canada | T-shirts | S | 100 | 150 | 200 |
| January | Canada | Jacket | S | 400 | 300 | NULL |
| January | USA | Jacket | L | NULL | 500 | 400 |

2. And I want to select rows where having same Month, Region, Category and Size values Nike price is higher than any of other's. For the table above result should be:

| Month | Region | Category | Size | Nike | Reebok | Puma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Canada | Jacket | S | 400 | 300 | NULL |

Comment: So what are you asking here? What is the logic to get the results you are after? What have *you* tried to solve the problem? Why didn't those attempts work or what about the materials you read didn't you understand? Why are you using a version of SQL Server than has been completely unsupported for almost 2 years?

Comment: Too many questions and no answers.....thanks

Comment: Yet you asked no questions, and you're the one that posted a question, @Magich ;) Please don't treat Stack Overflow like a "free coding service"; it isn't one.

Comment: "asked no questions" -> "posted a question" 0_0

Comment: @Larnu next time i'll put question mark in the end, thanks

Comment: At doesn't make it a question..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation and then some filtering.

```
select *
from (select Month, Region, Category, Size,  
             max(case when brand = 'Nike' then price end) as nike, 
             max(case when brand = 'Reebok' then price end) as Reebok, 
             max(case when brand = 'Puma' then price end) as Puma           
      from t
      group by Month, Region, Category, Size
     ) t
where nike > coalesce(Reebok, 0) and
      nike > coalesce(Puma, 0);
```